# Sqoop import multiple tables without exclude options

Tags: sqoop

I know that while importing tables from rdbms to hdfs using sqoop import we can use import-all-tables option to get multiple tables.
But what if I have 30 tables in my rdbms and need to import only 15.
What can be done in that case?

Thanks for suggestions.

Comment: Why u dont want to use --exclude option ?

Comment: @TKHN - The reason I don't wan't to use exclude option is due to the no. of tables being excluded.Suppose there are 1000 tables in my RDBMS and I want to import 600 of them.So shall I need to specify those remaining 400 tables in the --exclude option manually or is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

add `--exclude-tables` Comma separated list of tables to exclude from import process

shell script would be like:

```
#!/bin/bash

exclude="table1,table2"

import-all-tables --connect jdbc:XXXX -username XXX\ 
-P --warehouse-dir /my/dir --exclude-tables $exclude -m XX
```